# Unable to launch grails app using tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, intellij-idea

At present I am using Intellij IDE 2017 and using grails version 3.2.6. If I run the app with the built in server, the application is able to launch and navigate.

I have now setup a tomcat 8 locally and set artifact to exploded. Upon launching, I get the following error.

When at url: http://localhost:8080 (not working)

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve
>   view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

I created a controller (inventory) for testing and set index method to render a String. 
This works and renders the String.

url: http://localhost:8080/inventory (working)

But if I navigate to a view under this controller other than index, I get the same error as above:

url: http://localhost:8080/inventory/edit (not working)

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve
>   view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Only having this issue when trying to run on tomcat.